Active RF signal repeater
I have two stations, A and B.
Station A broadcasts a pure  10MHz sinusoidal signal on air. A very simple sine wave generator like a Colpitts oscillator makes the signal.  It is directly connected to an appropriate length antenna so the sine signal spreads over air.
I do not transfer any data with this signal.  I need it for carrier signal phase ranging.
I need station B to reflect back the signal it receives from A (regarding the received phase) and finally on A I can receive the signal and calculate the phase difference between sent and received signal and use it for finding distance between two stations.
I'm trying to repeat the same process which is done with laser for finding the distance (more info here), just replace the laser with RF. The image below shows the idea for laser range finding.

My problem is how to reflect back the signal at station B? Is there any well known mechanism for this?  For example, first let B go sync with signal received from A (for example, for 100ms station B listen to signal from A and try to sync with it, then spread back the wave while A is in listen mode?)
Edit
Just need to note that station A and B have clear sight of view to each other and distance is less that 15m (1/2 wavelength of 10mhz signal).

Have you considered the effect the wavelength of the signal will have on the distance resolution?

I think at 10MHZ, the wavelength would be about 30m. reading phase diff with 1 deg tolerance will result in 16cm resolution.

Won't most things absorb 10MHz?

@VoltageSpike you can see large metal objects with 10 MHz; think container ships. But yes, anything smaller than wavelength would mostly look like "diffuse material", not like a mirror, to RF.

so do i think that i need an active reflector instead of passive one. both stations have direct and clear eye view to each other, distance is less than say 100M always.

If station B is a passive reflector, you are reinventing RADAR.  The last R stands for Ranging.

Why do you call it AM when you don't mention anything about modulation, and in fact specifically say that it's a pure 10 MHz tone?

@Hearth, i did removed AM in title. thanks

First of all, your transmitter A would be illegal. And any conductive surface reflects electromagnetic waves; at 10 MHz, a sufficiently large metal sheet would do; there's no point in an active station. (10 MHz is a very bad choice here, with a large wavelengths you need large surfaces to get sharp reflections.) This all reads like you're not very familiar with the physical basics of radio waves, so I'll give a slightly superficial introduction further down.
But that aside, you are not recreating what is done with that laser: the Leica Lidar is modulating the laser beam (at a rate of 200 MHz, which is very small compared to the frequency of light), which is the opposite of what you're planning to do! Also, the Leica document has no second station. It simply uses reflections.
So, either you actually just want to build a pulse radar (easy to understand, hard to do with distances that aren't huge), or you are planning to consider an interferometric radar here, where you use an actual beam, formed by a directive antenna. You assume 10 MHz – an antenna that has any directivity at that frequency would be hundreds to thousands of meter in size!
So, in all honesty: Back to the study board. The fact that radio waves are reflected by metallic objects has been known since Maxwell (1861), and experimentally demonstrated by Hertz (1867); Radar (short for "Radio detection and ranging") was demonstrated to be feasible by Hülsmeyer in 1904. So, you have 120 years of science and technology that have been simplified, explained and documented to catch up on! That's great, because it means there's many good introductions to the very basics of electromagnetic waves and of radar around that you can choose from.
What you need is 1. to choose a carrier frequency significantly higher than 10 MHz, to keep the dimensions of your antenna(s) somewhat in check. Then need to realize that if you go for an unmodulated carrier wave (which, again, is the opposite of what is described by Leica), you only get information on distance that is ambiguous – it could be some distance D, or D plus half a wavelength, or D plus one full wavelength, or D plus three half wavelengths, or D plus any other integer multiple of a single wavelength. And: you need D to be much larger than a single wavelength, otherwise your antenna and the reflector aren't actually two separate things, but form a resonator, and nothing will work.
Or, you decide to modulate the carrier wave – and now you're in classic Radar territorry. FMCW radars are easy to understand, and seem to be close to be what you'd need. Not the same working principle as the Leica device, but in exchange you wouldn't have to go through the coarse/fine distance measurement state change and program a more complicated device.

First of all, thanks for the detailed answer. Why there is no point in using an active reflector?

Also about antenna size you are right, antenna for 10MHZ will be big. but i was thinking that a short dipole antennal would work for me as distance between A and B are fairly small (like 30m) and clear sight of view, like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJ23QziCMUM which is transmitting 8MHZ rf with a say 50cm dipole antenna for short distance

@epsi1on because the active reflector contributes nothing but uncertainty to your problem?

@epsi1on distance of 30m with a wavelength of 30m can't work. Again, you're clearly missing the very basics here!

OK, thanks for information. what if maximum distance between two stations be 15m?

Have you read my answer?? The distance must be significantly larger than a wavelength.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry you are right. Is this limitation (D significantly larger than wavelength) because of using a passive antenna? I mean maybe with active antenna there be no such limitation?

no. This is the fourth time I repeat this, so this is my last reaction, but: you're clearly missing RF basics, you need these first. You will not get around reading a basic book.
